# laravel elixir eact hmr did not working on state change

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs, webpack

I'm using **laravel** with react, I want to have hot reloading hence I try this example.

[Example from github](https://github.com/eumentis/laravel-elixir-react-hmr-demo)

The demo worked when I just the `jsx`, but not the state. For example in this file

[File](https://github.com/eumentis/laravel-elixir-react-hmr-demo/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/Counter.jsx)

I change and save the line 28, the hot reloading work, but when I change the line 6, I have to refresh to see the changes.